# How to attach events on control buttons of SAPUI5's Network Graphs?

Tags: javascript, graph, sapui5

I am creating a Network Graph based on this official code sample https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.suite.ui.commons.networkgraph.Graph/sample/sap.suite.ui.commons.sample.NetworkGraphDimensions

I would like to disable search field (make it invisible) by default and enable it only after switching to Full Screen Mode.

Disabling search field by default is easy:

```
var oNetworkGraph = this.getView().byId("myGraphId");

if (oNetworkGraph.isFullScreen() === false) {       
    oNetworkGraph._searchField.setVisible(false);
}
```

The problem is that our search field and other buttons (zoom in/out, toggle legend button, etc) are not defined inside XML view neither inside controllers. I guess it's a part of either `sap.suite.ui.commons.networkgraph` or `sap.suite.ui.commons.networkgraph.layout` and being inserted on init.

Because of this issue I can't add a listener on my Full Screen Toggle Button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could attach yourself similarly to your search field modifications.

I've checked the code and the button is available under the class variable `_oFullScreenButton`. That means by `oNetworkGraph._oFullScreenButton.attachPress(function() {});` You could run code when button is pressed.

Note that accessing these private APIs might break in future versions.